# How do i center a card horizontally and vertically i.e in the very center of the activity

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I want to center a card which should be centered horizontally and vertically i am trying to achieve this through Positioned widget but unable to do so.

This is what i am getting:
[image]

Here is my code:

```html
Positioned(
                 
                child:
              Card(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius:BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                  side: BorderSide(color: Color.fromRGBO(214, 0, 27, 1)),
                ),
                  child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                              child: Text("hello@xyz.com",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontSize: 16)),
                            )
                          ],
                        ))
               ],
                ),
              ),
              ),
```

Comment: Use [Center](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Center-class.html) widget.

Comment: This will not work with positioned widget i need to use center widget to acheive this?

Comment: Yes. Use `Center` widget instead of `Positioned`.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap Your Card with a Center widget, It automatically centers it

Answer (score 0):

Before your widgets, use the Center widget.

```
 Card(
    child: Center(
    child: YourWidgets()
    ))
```

Comment: i did tried it by                    Center(
                child:Center(
                  
               child:
              Card(

Comment: did not have any effect